# Why can't I download files from s3 bucket, when permissions are set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions

I was trying to create a bucket and set full permissions for two more accounts. First, I added those accounts in bucket Permissions. Files were still inaccessible. Then, I tried a policy. I created two roles for each account to specify them in it. Here is that policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::id:role/user1",
                    "arn:aws:iam::id:role/user2"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Still nothing. Then I saw, that even though bucket has all the permissions set, files in it don't have any. When I set them for a file, it becomes accessible for other users. But I wouldn't really want to do that for each file I upload. What's wrong?

I tried loading up files with aws cli and set permissions there with a "--grants" option, but after uploading, I can't even download them myself via the aws console.

Comment: Just checking the obvious: 1. your policy has been attached to the roles;  2. they are roles rather than users?

Comment: @craigcaulfield, yes, they are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To demonstrate how this works, I did the following:

- Created `bucket-1` in Account-1
- Assigned this **bucket policy**:

.

```
{
    "Id": "Account1Policy",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowBucketAccess",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-1/*"
            ],
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:user/account-2-user"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy says: *Allow account2:account-2-user to do anything with account1:bucket-1*

- Created `account-2-user` in Account-2
- Gave the user this **inline policy**:

.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowBucket1Access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy says: *Allow the user to whom this policy is attached permission to do anything with bucket-1*

If both the bucket and the user were in the same account, this policy would be sufficient to grant full access to the bucket. However, because bucket-1 actually belongs to a different account, the first policy (above) is also required so that account-1 actually grants access. This means that the 2nd policy isn't actually granting access to the bucket - it is merely granting permission for `account-user-2` to *make a request* to access the bucket. The real access is granted in the first policy.

I then successfully used the credentials of `account-2-user` to access `bucket-1`:

```
$ aws s3 cp foo.txt s3://bucket-1 --profile account-2-user
upload: ./foo.txt to s3://bucket-1/foo.txt
```

Comment: I've done all of this and successfully loaded up the file, yes, thank you. But one last question. I can't download that file with Account-1 if I don't use '--grants' option in cli. Is this how it's supposed to be. I should always grant permissions for each new file?

Comment: You do NOT need to assign object-level permissions. The above policies are all that is necessary. You say "I can't download that file with Account-1", but my answer focuses on granting access to `account-2-user`, which has nothing to do with a user in Account 1. If you want a user in Account 1 to access the bucket, you will either need to assign permissions to the User in account 1, or modify the Bucket Policy to permit access by the User in account 1.

Comment: I have modified the bucket policy and added the user from the first account. And added inline policy for that user in the 1st account. But still, if a file is loaded by the user in the second account, the first account can't open/download it, unless I explicitly give it a permission.

Comment: I'm totally confused by your scenario. If the above has solved your first problem (cross-account access), feel free to ask a second question about your current issue. The solutions will not interfere with each other.

Comment: Yes, it solved my problem of accessing files when loading up with aws cli with different accounts. But my initial question was about downloading and now I see that question was a bit misguiding. It is alright now, anyway. I figured out about the downloading part, thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If a bucket policy grants access to an object, you do not need to also grant access at the object-level.

The bucket policy you have listed would grant access to the bucket if it is being accessed via credentials that are issued from a **role** that is called `user1` or `user2`. (It's quite strange that you are giving 'user' prefixes to role names.)

For example, if you have an Amazon EC2 instance that is assigned an IAM role called `user1`, then it will be automatically given credentials to access the bucket.

If `user1` and `user2` are actually users, then the ARN should be:

```
arn:aws:iam::id:user/user1
```

In this case, the bucket will be accessible when accessed the that user's credentials.

**Update:**

I think it actually needs permissions to be assigned in two locations:

1. **On the Bucket** in Account-1, as per above (which says that the bucket is permitting access from a user/role in another account), AND
2. **On the user/role** in Account-2 as well, which says that the administrator of Account-2 is permitting that user/role to call S3. If the user/role already has `s3:*` permissions against `*` resources, then this isn't needed. At a minimum it needs permissions against S3 for the desired bucket.

Comment: I've just changed the names here, they are called differently there. Now, it's probably a dumb question, but I created these roles on my own account. Should they be created on 2 other accounts? And I think you wanted to say, that the ARN you provided is for **users**, not for **roles**, right?

Comment: More details added.

Comment: Thank you, @JohnRotenstein, I've created a user on Account-2 with "AmazonS3FullAccess" and put its ARN in the bucket policy in Account-1. There is still no permission. I would also like to know: Do I have to set permissions for each account whenever I upload the file, or if the bucket is shared, that means any uploaded files in the future should be accessible. Because, right now, when I upload the file and set permissions on it, it is accessible from other accounts.

Comment: I added another answer to clarify things.